# Android Studio imports Kotlin Dependencies into Java File

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I recently had to reimport my android project, which consists of both `.java` and `.kt` files, into Android Studio. After the import Android Studio tries to import only some Kotlin dependencies into `.java` files, what obviously doesn't work.

The same code had worked before, what makes me think I may be missing some setting in Android Studio, about how Java and Kotlin interact or something like that?

[image]

Edit: On the other hand I'm able to build my app and also deploy to a device without problems, but Android Studio still keeps complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Check your kotlin version(make sure that you have the latest one ) then clean and rebuild your app

Comment: not working for me. i also tried invalidating the cache but without success

Answer (score 0):

try to hard-import

```
import java.lang.Deprecated;
```

but I think you can resolve this issue by the way clean and rebuild your project

Comment: even hard-import doesn't work correctly, it tells me right at the import statement that symbol 'Deprecated' cannot be resolved. importing java.lang.* leads to 'Unused import statement'